# Python Selenium driver not detecting changes in iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Once I'm logged in, I switch to the iframe in question:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("ucSC")
```

I then search for a search button, and click it.

```
search_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DERIVED_SSS_SCR_SSS_LINK_ANCHOR1"]')
search_btn.click()
```

Clicking this search button causes a bunch of new things to appear inside the iframe.

Right now I am trying to switch out of the iframe and switch back into it, hoping that would change something.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()


driver.switch_to.frame("ucSC")
```

But it changes nothing because when I try to print the current page, I can see from the output that the iframe looks the same as it did before I clicked Search.

```
print driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")
```

So now I can't find elements inside the iframe, in the browser I can see that the iframe has changed but driver does not seem to recognize that.

I've done a lot of searching but this is my first time using python and selenium so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Let `Clicking this search button causes a bunch of new things to appear inside the iframe`, but why would you `switch out of the iframe and switch back into it`? What are your next steps which you would perform?

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on so I was just experimenting. I realize now that switching makes no difference. When search is clicked, new elements from a database are populated inside the iframe.

The next step is to locate an elements inside the iframe, I was trying to do it like this:


SubjectList = driver.find_element_by_id("SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_SUBJECT_SRCH$0")


Which gives me this error "Cannot find context with specified id"

All of the tutorials online talk about swtiching between frames but have not found any info on how to handle changes within frames.

Comment: `SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_SUBJECT_SRCH$0` looks dynamic to me. Share the `HTML` and your exact `Manual Step` which you are trying to `Automate`.

Comment: It is dynamic, I'm just trying to make a program that will log into my university's site and check if a course is open.

Not sure if for example, I need to look into handling AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had to do an explicit wait after updating the iframe.

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```